# What's the meaning of this C++ struct?

Tags: c++, struct, overloading

I got a simple C++ struct as follows:

```
// Functor for peak to decreasing intensity sorting
struct cmp_decr_int2
{
    bool operator() (peak2 a, peak2 b) 
    { 
        return a.int2 > b.int2;
    }   
};
```

is there an overload of the operator in this sample?

Comment: Sorry again, I apologize for that

Comment: Note that in C++ a `struct` is just a `class` with default accessibility being `public`. The question is not specific to `struct`, neither are the answers.

Answer (score 10):

Yes. `operator()` is called the "function call" operator, and allows an object to be usable as if it were a function. Such a class is called a "functor".

A common pattern is to make functors that compare two things for equality or relations, for use in anything requiring a comparison predicate. (This one could be usable in an `std::map`, for example. It would have a member like`cmp_decr_int2 compare;` and then it could compare the relation between two things with: `if (compare(x, y)) /* x is less than y, by some metric */`)

This particular struct orders two `peak2`'s by comparing their `int2` members. It could be better written as:

```
struct cmp_decr_int2
{
    //                     note const! vvvvv
    bool operator() (peak2 a, peak2 b) const
    { 
        return a.int2 > b.int2;
    }   
};
```

The function should be `const` because it does not need to change any members (there are none to change.) [`const`-correctness](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html) is important.*

In many cases these functors are used in contexts where the arguments themselves are `const`, so you should either take the arguments by value as in the example or by constant reference.

You should prefer to pass types by const-reference over by-value, except when that type is fundamental (float, unsigned int, double, etc.) or smaller than a `void*`. In most cases, then, you will pass by const-reference:

```
struct cmp_decr_int2
{
    // note const&:  vvvvv       v    vvvvv       v    vvvvv
    bool operator() (const peak2 & a, const peak2 & b) const
    { 
        return a.int2 > b.int2;
    }   
};
```

<sub>*If this were used as a predicate in a `std::map`, for example, without `const` the map wouldn't be able to compare two things while within a `const` function.</sub>

Comment: And if the `peak2` objects are not really small, the arguments should also be const references.

Comment: I have tried to add it there. Feel free to adapt the style as you like, as it is *your* answer (and english is not my mother tongue). :)

Comment: @David: I didn't know English isn't your native language, couldn't tell. :)

Comment: Excuse me, what is peak2 in this case? is it a class? it should have the attribute "int2", what is it ?

Comment: @ladyfafa: It's definitely a class type, but that's all we can say. `int2` is probably an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Structs in C++ are just classes with a default accessor of public instead of private. So yes, that would have a function overload.

Answer (score 0):

in c++ a struct is in every way like a class, except that the default parameter access is `public:` rather than `private:`.  It is a common practice to use struct instead of class when  the scope of the defined type's use is very narrow, such as in the example of a simple functor.

What this example does is emulate the appearance of a function pointer without the fragility of possibly being null.

The `operator()` member here overloads function calling.  when you try to do something like:

```
cmp_decr_int2 foo;
foo(peek2(), peek2());
```

that overload member gets called.

Comment: that was very detailed for a beginner, really helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct cmp_decr_int2
{
    bool operator() (int a, int b)
    { 
        return a > b;
    }

    bool operator() (int i)
    {
        return i > 0;
    }
};

int main()
{
    cmp_decr_int2 a;
    cout << a(1, 2) << endl;
    cout << a(1) << endl;
}
```

Yep, sure can overload the function!  This worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

$13.5.4 states-

operator() shall be a non-static member function with an arbitrary number of parameters. It can have default arguments. It implements the function call syntax postfix-expression ( expression-listopt ) where the postfix-expression evaluates to a class object and the possibly empty expression-list matches the parameter list of an operator() member function of the class. Thus, a call x(arg1,...) is interpreted as x.operator()(arg1, ...) for a class object x of type T if T::operator()(T1, T2, T3) exists and if the operator is selected as the best match function by the overload resolution mechanism (13.3.3).

Therefore, the struct 'cmp_decr_int2' has definitely overloaded operator().

Note that this is also the only operator in C++ that can take variable number of arguments.